# Click a link with href attribute and execute the Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

My script contains a link `a` element with `href` attribute of "#login" as below.

```
<a href="#login">Login</a>
```

I want to my Javascript function detect the "href" element in the link and execute. How can I do this? My Javascript function is

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName("a[href=#login]").onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("working");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why have I seen no querySelector love in these answers?

If you want to use that CSS selector to grab your link, nothing is stopping you:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector("a[href='#login']").onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("working");
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#login">Login</a>
```

**EDIT:**
I saw in another answer that you believe there may be multiple links on a page that match that selector, in which case you'll need to loop through them:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='#login']"),
      //always create anonymous functions outside of a loop :)
      click = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("working");
      }, i;
  for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = click;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#login">Login</a>
<a href="#login">Login</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#login" onclick="getValue()">Login</a>

function getValue()
{
    alert("working");
    e.preventDefault();  
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hk87V/34/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `getElementsByTagName` is treating it like a jquery selector, which it is not designed to do.

It would be much simpler to give the tag an `id` and use [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("loginLink").onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("working");
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="#login" id="loginLink">Login</a>
```

If for whatever reason you cannot change the html and you want to do it this way you would need to get *all* `a` tags then loop through each one to test the `href` attribute. Note you need to use `a.getAttribute("href")` to get "#login", rather than just `a.href` which oftens give you an full URL:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for(var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
    var a = aTags[i];
    if(a.getAttribute("href") == "#login") {
      a.onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("working");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#login">Login</a>
<a href="#test">Test</a>
<a href="#login">Login Again</a>
```